# Postgres HTML query dispay result as table

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I am battling severely with what I think is a PHP problem as I have no previous knowledge of using PHP. My end goal is to allow  a user to select values from a drop down menu which will be passed to a select statement and will return a table of results in an HTML format. Is this possible?

I am using a PostgreSQL database and have managed to get some PHP together, whether it is correct or not I am unsure. I have also installed Apache Tomcat.

My code is:

```
<?php 

$host = "my_host"; 
$user = "postgres"; 
$password = "my_password"; 
$db = "my_db"; 

$con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$password")
    or die ("Could not connect to server\n"); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM rev_3.inyaninga_sewer_pipelines LIMIT 5"; 

$rs = pg_query($con, $query) or die("Cannot execute query: $query\n");

    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($rs)) {
                 echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row[4]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row[5]</td>";
                 echo "</tr>";
                 }
                 pg_close($con);
                 ?>


?>
```

At this point absolutely any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting output? What is your specific question?

Comment: If I run the php it displays the complete code in the browser. I'm also unsure whether the code is actually correct in terms of the request sent to the postgresql database

Comment: `My end goal is to allow a user to select values from a drop down menu which will be passed to a select statement and will return a table of results in an HTML format` use ajax with your dropdown

Comment: @CamMuller - "_... it displays the complete code in the browser_". Are you saying that the _sourcecode_ is displayed in the browser or that the _query result_ is displayed in the browser?